# Changing type @article to look kind of like @book

Tags: biblatex

I've got lots of articles, and normally I use the `@book` type to put them to my references because I don't like the look of the article type. But right now I think that's a bit to botchy like I am doing it.

So my question, is there an easy way to tweak the `@article` type instead of creating an own on.

For example, that is how it looks like when I am using `@article` type.

```
@article{Mooney.1940,
    author = {Mooney,M.},
    title = {A Theory of Large Elastic Deformation},
    journal = {Journal of Applied Physics},
    volume = {11},
    number = {9},
    pages = {582-592},
    year = {1940},
}
```

[image]

And that is how I want it to look like.

[image]

As you can see there is quite a bit of change to it.

I add a minimal example with the settings I've already changed in my bibliography.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}{Literatur.bib}
    @article{Mooney.1940,
        author = {Mooney,M.},
        title = {A Theory of Large Elastic Deformation},
        journal = {Journal of Applied Physics},
        volume = {11},
        number = {9},
        pages = {582-592},
        year = {1940},
    }
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{Literatur.bib}

%comma instead of point
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space} 

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    
Test \cite[S.7]{Mooney.1940}

\printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do that with [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-numeric,
  articlein=false,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space} 

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}

\renewcommand*{\jourvoldelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\volnumdatedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\bibstring{jourvol}~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuedate}{#1}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\jourvoldelim}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\jourserdelim}%
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\servoldelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \setunit{\volnumdatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{note+pages}{}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Mooney.1940,
  author  = {Mooney, M.},
  title   = {A Theory of Large Elastic Deformation},
  journal = {Journal of Applied Physics},
  volume  = {11},
  number  = {9},
  pages   = {582-592},
  year    = {1940},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[7]{Mooney.1940}
ipsum \autocite[371]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Mooney, M.: A Theory of Large Elastic Deformation, Journal of Applied Physics, Jg. 11, Nr. 9, S. 582–592, 1940.]

Note that you don't have to (and indeed should not) include the "S." in the postnote argument for the page (range). `biblatex` automatically adds the appropriate page prefix.

You also won't need `bibencoding=utf8,` since `biblatex` can automatically infer that from the remaining settings in your code (the `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`).

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. Yeah, about that part with the page "S." I put it only in plain text as an example here.  I know that's not necessary, and you figured it out because of the size of the hyphen. I marked this question as answered because it really is,  but could you tell me which part is responsible for the Jg., please?

Comment: @JuliaS `\bibstring{jourvol}`. If you insist on "Bd.", add `\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{jourvol = {Bd\adddot}}` to the preamble.